# How to Generate "config.php" via PHP Form?

Tags: php

I'm building a small php-based application which requires a "config.php" file containing a username and password. Rather than requiring the end user to modify "config.php" manually before they upload the application to their server, I would like to dynamically generate "config.php" from a setup form.

**Basically, I'd like to use this:**

```
<form method="POST" action="?setup-config">
<fieldset>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <label for="username">Desired User Name</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <label for="password">Desired Password</label>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Save Username &amp; Password">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**to create "config.php":**

```
<?php

$username = 'entered username';
$password = 'entered password';
```

Comment: Use [`frwite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: What? No, no, no, no, no. Usernames and passwords belong in a database. Period. And the passwords need to be secured through a hash.

Comment: @Matt - I agree in principle, but there's nothing wrong with storing user login data for small applications in the file system so long as it's (a) Outside the document root; and (b) You hash the password data (as you mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `file_put_contents()`:

```
$config[] = "<?php";
$config[] = "\$username = '$_POST['username']';";
$config[] = "\$password = '$_POST['password']';";

file_put_contents("config.php", implode("\n", $config));
```

Comment: You're not using the correct operators. You need to use the concatination operator: `.=`... otherwise you'll just have `$config = "\$password = '$_POST['password']';\n"` in the config file.

Comment: True, updated to use my preferred syntax. I prefer arrays and implode for scalability, although something of this small of scale, concating the vars would be fine.

Comment: I like the `file_put_contents()` method as well

Answer (score 1):

A **very** basic example. This can be improved upon *a lot*.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('config.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "<?php\n");
fwrite($fp, "\$username = '$_POST['username']';\n");
fwrite($fp, "\$password = '$_POST['password']';\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```